# Auth0 Management API Token returns 401, Invalid signature received for JSON Web Token validation

Tags: auth0

I am trying to get an auth0 token which allows me to create/update users on auth0 through my backend service for user management.

I followed the instructions at https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2/tokens,(`Auth0 Management API -> API Explorer -> Copy Token`) to generate the token. However, the token doesn't work for me. I get a 401 status response with the body below:

```
{
  "statusCode": 401,
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "message": "Invalid signature received for JSON Web Token validation",
  "attributes": {
    "error": "Invalid signature received for JSON Web Token validation"
  }
}
```

I added all scoped just to be safe. I tried both ruby auth0 client and the UI for testing tokens at https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2

I did not find a solution yet at the auth0 forum so asking here. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and managed to fix it.

It was the `expiry` in the token which I set to very large. The token generated however had value for the expiry as `null`. This was breaking the authentication.

I then set the token expiry far into the future(300 years) and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than set a large expiration, consider using Client Credentials grant flow and re-requesting new token when the exising one expires. This is a much safer option as your token would expire say 24 hours after it was leaked in the event of a security breach.

Here is an [example code on how to achieve this](https://github.com/tawawa/auth0-api-node-calls/blob/master/auth0-api/api.js#L4) together with a [simple test for that code](https://github.com/tawawa/auth0-api-node-calls/blob/master/test/test.js#L16).

If you have any questions, please feel free to leave comments below.